# What vacation tracking software do you use for a small company?

Tags: calendar, tracking

Looking for an interface that is nice.  Free would be cool but it doesn't have to be

**Edit:** I would like to know how many vacation/sick/floater days are remaining for the year for the person. I would also like a tool where employees can request a day off and an approver would approve of it

Comment: Isn't it built in to your time reporting system?

Comment: We dont have one.  Its a small software company.   We currently do things in an outlook calendar but its not a great system

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a calendar that anyone in your company can see and add their own vacation time, then I suggest Google Calendar. You can easily create a calendar and share among many people.

You might take it one step further and go with Google Apps. That way you could just open the calendar to the entire company instead of having to invite/remove people individually.

Comment: I would like to know how many vacation/sick/floater days are remaining for the year for the person.  I would also like a tool where employees can request a day off and an approver would approve of it

Comment: I suggest that you update your question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

[TrackSmart](http://www.tracksmart.com) may meet your needs. It is aimed at small to mid sized companies for attendance tracking and recordkeeping. Subscription plans include additional time off pools for vacation, sick and personal as well as more employees and reports.

We also have a mobile app ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tracksmart-employee-self-service/id644084366) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tracksmart.android)) for employees to request time off and enter time sheets.

*DISCLAIMER: I am one of the developers.*

Comment: This is no longer free for any amount of employees it seems.

Comment: Yes, we have moved to a free trial model.

Answer (score 0):

We use Harvest for time tracking. But it lacks vacation day counting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple that I believe meet all your requirements.  Neither one is free, but both seem to be robust and scalable apps.

- [iemployee.com](http://www.iemployee.com/)
- [whosoff.com](http://www.whosoff.com)

Answer (score 0):

MrTickTock is a simple web base time tracker with **vacation tracking** functionality. Good choice for small company. User can mark day and week as Off or Sick. Team mates can see absence of each other. The interface is really smooth and simple.

There is no information on vacation/sick days remaining and no request-approve support yet.

MrTickTock is free and available at http://mrticktock.com

Answer (score -1):

I'm an iPhone app developer and I made an app to solve this problem!

It's called Time Off. It allows your employees to track their own time off and report it back to you, OR you can use the app to track their time for them.

Check it out at:  www.mytimeoffapp.com

If you have any questions please let me know.